Is macro execution supported in OpenXML SDK,do we have any APIs for that
We have a template which will fetch data from database and genreate a report.We are using OpenXML SDK to generate the Excel report.All non-macro templates will work in this way,but for macro enables templates,how to run macro in open xml mode.As of now we are using Server side automation APIs for this.But now mocrosoft is not recommending server side automation.And we are getting failures if we run multiple templates together in Server side automation for running macro.
So my question is ,is there a way to run macro based templates in open xml mode.Will there be any API for this,or how we can sort server side automation issues.
We have a template which will fetch data from database and generate a report.We are using OpenXML SDK to generate the Excel report.All non-macro templates will work in this way,but for macro enables templates,how to run macro in open xml mode.As of now we are using Server side automation APIs for this.But now mocrosoft is not recommending server side automation.And we are getting failures if we run multiple templates together in Server side automation for running macro.
So my question is ,is there a way to run macro based templates in open xml mode.Will there be any API for this,or how we can sort server side automation issues.
